# Most common letter in word Python

Tags: python, string

I need to get the most common letter of given word. Well, that's what i need

Find the most common letter in the given word. If any letters repeat the same times, output the less symbol. (word1 < word2)

```
word = input()
repeats = 1
for i in word:
    p = word.count(i)
    if p > repeats:
        repeats = p
        res = i
```

I can't do the last task

> If any letters repeat the same times, output the less symbol. (word1 < word2)

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs/outputs to make it clear?

Comment: @DanielHao yes, 'testsample' - 'e' e < t, s

Comment: It's not clear about the ^^^ logic here?  why ```e < t, s```?

Comment: I don't understand last task.

Comment: it seems you have to remeber all chars which have the same `count()` - so `res` has to be list and you have to check also `p == repeats` to append other chars to this list `res.append(i)`. And `p > repeats:` will have to create new list `res = [i]` And later you will have to get char with smaller ASCII code - maybe with `min()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
word = input().lower()
counter_list = []
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for l in letters:
    counter_list.append(word.count(l))

i = counter_list.index(max(counter_list))
print(letters[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` here,

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: Counter('most common letter of given word').most_common(1)
Out[2]: [('o', 5)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can i check the less letter with this? For example "testsample" should return e (e < t, s but s = 2, e = 2, t = 2)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `list` or better `set` to keep all chars with the same count.
And later you can use `min()` to get correct result from `list` or `set`:

```
#word = input()
word = 'testsample'

repeats = 0

for char in word:
    count = word.count(char)
    #print(char, count)
    
    if count > repeats:
        repeats = count
        result = set(char)  # create new `set()`
        #result = [char]    # create new `list()`
    elif count == repeats:
        result.add(char)      # add to existing `set()`
        #result.append(char)  # add to existing `list()`
        
print('all:', result)
        
print('min:', min(result))
```

Result:

```
all: {'s', 'e', 't'}
min: e
```